# Preventing Eclipse from exporting an EAR with problems

Tags: eclipse, ear

On Eclipse Indigo EE IDE for web devs, for Win7, I have two projects. A web application and an EAR project that contains it and does nothing else.

I discovered (the hard way) that I can export the EAR project into an EAR file, even when the web application has compilation problems. Eclipse just does its best effort to compile all the parts that can and leaving the rest messed up.

Is there any way to prevent Eclipse from exporting an EAR if there's any Error task, or any compilation problem? I used to have an ant script for this, which would stop the building process on any error, but I am not allowed to use an ant script in this new project.